# How to synchronize our DATAStax database with Network Time Protocol (NTP Server) of National Informatics Centre (NIC) over NPL

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

How to synchronize our DATA Stax database with Network Time Protocol (NTP Server) of National Informatics Centre (NIC) over National Physical Laboratory (NPL)  is traceable to  NTP servers for synchronisation of our infrastructure ICT system clocks (INDIA).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should take your time and read the article to make your question more clear for us: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.